# SQL Server job scheduling and PHP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've been developing an application that displays graphs on a website by reading from a SQL Server. Since some of the tables are very large, my SQL scripts take a couple minutes to execute, so I devised a plan to get around this by having a job execute on a monthly basis. I have my T-SQL scripts that process the data and other scripts to create and display the graphs, so the hard part is done. The problem I'm having is creating a scheduled job in SQL Server 2005 (cant upgrade since it's a work computer).

I've been having a great deal of trouble as it seems I don't have the stored procedures installed necessary to create a job or schedule. For example, when I ran:

```
USE TEST1 ;
GO
EXEC sp_add_job
@job_name = N'MY_FIRST_JOB2' ;
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
@job_name = N'MY_FIRST_JOB2',
@step_name = N'Set database to read only',
@subsystem = N'TSQL',
@command = N'SELECT * FROM [TEST1].[dbo].[BACK1]', 
@retry_attempts = 5,
@retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
```

I received errors saying the stored procedures sp_add_job and sp_add_jobstep could not be found. I tried putting [dbo] before the stored procedures and it didn't help. When I checked my Programmability -> Stored Procedures -> System Stored Procedure folder, there were a lot but none for jobs or scheduling! Interestingly, when I ran

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[procedures];
```

I got nothing, not a single row other than the column headers.

When I tried using the interface in SQL Server Agent, I'm able to create a job and set the schedule but it's not executing. When I open the job, the last executed box doesn't always update even though it should have executed. Furthermore, in the view history/logs, only a few of my attempts appeared (all errored out) for different reasons, some were due to permission even when I set the user to NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM.

This brings me to 2 questions:

1) Is there a way I can download these stored procedures?

2) Is there any other way I can do this? I have access to SQLExpress but since it doesn't have scheduling and the SQL Server Agent, I opted out and chose the easier route.

I've been at this for a while and am at wits end.

Comment: After some googling and reading on here, I found that many people recommended SQL Scheduler. It worked on the first try, so I'm sticking with my SQL Express. I'm still stumped as to why my full SQL Server with SQL Server Agent is missing some of the stored procedures but I'm guessing I'll have to ask for it to be re-installed or tackle it at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the stored procedures you are referencing are not part of the database.  All of the job related system stored procedures are in the msdb database.

An example of a proper call would be:

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
@job_name = N'MY_FIRST_JOB2';`